# zend framework text fields with same name but with different belongings

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with zend form, where i need to built a form where field name are same but with different belongings. Here is the input fields that i wanted inside my form.

Currently i am getting with straight html but because of this i am missing validation.

```
<input type="text" name="travel_guide_tab[4][title]">
<input type="text" name="travel_guide_tab[4][description]">
<input type="text" name="travel_guide_tab[6][title]">
<input type="text" name="travel_guide_tab[6][description]">
```

Comment: Please explain further how are you trying to validate. You can validate at server side in case you are using client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

In Zend Form the element names must be unique (in some way) or else they will overwrite. However you can continue using your html form and simply filter and validate in the controller using [Zend_Filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html). The [filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html) and [validation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) classes are the same ones used by Zend_Form you just pass the data in a different way.

Simple example, partial:

```
public function someAction() {
        //set filters and validators for Zend_Filter_Input
        $filters = array(
            'nameOfInput' => array('HtmlEntities', 'StripTags')
        );
        $validators = array(
            'nameOfInput' => array('NotEmpty', 'Int')
        );
        //assign Input
        $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);//can also pass the data in constructor (optional)
        $input->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
            //check input is valid and is specifically posted as 'Delete Selected'
            if ($input->isValid()) {
            //do some stuff
            }
```

Good Luck.